# SQL Performance Issue ASP.Net App

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, query-performance

We have a performance Issue in our ASP.NET based web App and it's visible only once when we login in the morning. As per Log looks like below query takes more than 1 minute 20 secs. Next time onward when user login to the app and try to access same page doesn't find any issue. Can you please let me know how to optimize this query ? Any thoughts how we can fix this problem ?

Log -

```
"11/13/15","08:38:27","ExecuteSql - ---3---- ","8",""
"11/13/15","08:38:27","ExecuteSql - ---4---- : SQL : SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(varchar(15), Period_End_Date, 107) as PDate FROM PBHISTORY..STATEMENT_OF_CHANGE 
                                               ORDER BY Period_End_Date DESC","8",""
"11/13/15","08:39:48","ExecuteSql - ---5---- ","8",""
```

SQL :

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    CONVERT(varchar(15), Period_End_Date, 107) as PDate 
FROM  
   PBHISTORY..STATEMENT_OF_CHANGE
ORDER BY 
   Period_End_Date DESC
```

C# ASP.NET -

```
public string GetDateRangeReportingDate(int reportId)
{
    var report = GetReportInfoById(reportId);
    string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(varchar(15), Period_End_Date, 107) as PDate FROM {0}..{1} ORDER BY Period_End_Date DESC", _historyDatabase, report.SourceTableName);

    var data = ExecuteSql(sql);

    while (data.Read())
    {
        return data["PDate"].ToString();
    }

    return null;
}

private SqlDataReader ExecuteSql(string sql)
{
     SqlDataReader reader;
     SqlConnection conn;

     var commandTimeOut = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PBReportCommandTimeout"].ToString();
     string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PBReportCS"].ConnectionString;

     conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
     conn.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
     cmd.CommandTimeout = int.Parse(commandTimeOut);

     reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     return reader;
}
```

Comment: How many records are you fetching ?

Comment: Avoid inline SQL, also ny class implementing the IDisposable interface should be wrapped in a using statement...  These are both performance concerns -- I can only imagine what other flaws are in the system.

Comment: Is there an index on that column?

Comment: Eldho - Only one Record. When I run the query in SQL Server Studio doesn't take more than 3 sec to execute.

Comment: Marco - Yes there are two indexes in STATEMENT_OF_CHANGE Table. idx_pedate_port and NONCIXPortfolioIDPeriodEndDate.

Comment: David - Can you please be little more specific ? Can you please modify the code and let me know how we can make it better ?

Comment: Is the app pool set to auto recycle every day? I would turn that off and see if that fixes it. Sounds like it recycles overnight and the initial request takes a while which is a common thing with asp.net

Comment: DB indexing wins the Game! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my performance issue I mentioned above. Issue was wrong indexing in table and I fixed this issue by changing the indexing of table where from we are fetching records in production.

Also, I fixed Framework level entity class by using SQL Data Adapter and using statements. App runs super fast in production. Thanks for your help.

private string ExecuteSqlNew(string sql)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PBReportCS"].ConnectionString;
            string commandTimeOut = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PBReportCommandTimeout"].ToString();
            DataSet result = new DataSet();
            string pDate = "";

```
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = int.Parse(commandTimeOut);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    adapter.Fill(result);
                    adapter.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                    pDate = result.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PDate"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return pDate;
```

}